# What if partial derivatives don't commute ( $\partial_x\partial_y \neq \partial_y\partial_x$ )?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Text books about college math generally only deal with cases in which partial derivatives commute. But what does it mean if partial derivatives don't commute?

My questions are:

1. What does it mean if $\partial_x\partial_y f(x,y) \neq \partial_y\partial_x f(x,y)$ ?
2. Is there math theory about this case?

Comment: If you start doing Riemannian geometry (the natural equivalent of) derivatives no longer commute in general. The curvature measures their failure to do so.

Comment: Have a look at this counterexample: https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Failure_of_Clairaut's_theorem_where_both_mixed_partials_are_defined_but_not_equal
Partial derivatives fail to commute if the function is not twice continuously differentiable.

Comment: Read more into Needham, you'll find the answer

Answer (score 1):

The symmetry of second order derivatives is known as  Schwarz's theorem, Clairaut's theorem, or Young's theorem: [Wiki page on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)

To answer your question:

1. It means that the second partial derivatives of f(x, y) are not continuous in a neighborhood of the input (x, y).
2. Yes, take a look at this: [Proof of Young's theorem](https://web.archive.org/web/20060518134739/http://are.berkeley.edu/courses/ARE210/fall2005/lecture_notes/Young%27s-Theorem.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The Schwarz's theorem says that if a function $f$ in a domain $\Omega$ is twice differentiable, then the second partial derivates commute.

If you have $1$ you can claim that the function isn't twice differentiable.

2. A theory I know about this kind of situations is the Sobolev Spaces. This spaces are useful when you have a *weak* derivate. That means the derivate is not continuos.
   For example $W^{2,\infty}(0,1)$ is the space of functions where the function, first and second weak derivates are bounded in $(0,1)$.

You can learn more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space).